# How can I change positive value to zero in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two columns for the time in and time out of the employee, and I want to determine their lates and undertimes. But I cannot properly do it, I already can do the negative value to zero but I just want to know how to do the positive value to zero.

This is my formula =(G10-C10)*1440 then as per my column values it will show a positive value but I want the positive value become ZERO

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give an example of what you mean by "I just want to know how to do the positive value to zero"?

Comment: This is my formula `=(G10-C10)*1440` then as per my column values it will show a positive value but I want the positive value become ZERO.

Comment: What of the negative ones? Should they remain negative?

Comment: Yes the negative will remain as negative.

Comment: If you're not going to use the result in any other calculation, you can use custom number formatting, such as this: `"0";-0;0`

Comment: I will use the result on other sheet, I'll just compute the total of negative values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `IF`, which would be the most popular choice:

```
=IF(G10-C10>0,0,(G10-C10)*1440)
```

Could be read as, 'if the difference is greater than 0 (positive), then put 0, otherwise put the difference itself'.

Or a little less common, but simpler:

```
=MIN((G10-C10)*1440,0)
```

Comment: I'll try this! Thanks!

Comment: @JoshuaDelaCruz No problem ^^

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to Jerry's answer, after applying your original formula, you can change the format of the cells to something like this:

```
"0";-0;0
```

- The first 0 is for positive. The quotes around it make sure the zero gets displayed literally.
- The second section (each section separated by a semi-colon `;`) is for negative and the last one's for zero values.
- The zero without quotes here means that one number should get displayed compulsorily.

Here's the output:

[image: Number formatting]

Comment: Thanks for this man! But it doesn't work well if I use the value for another computation. Thank you very much!